# Spring Data for Cassandra - CassandraOperations get max of column

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am developing Spring Boot app to connect to Cassandra using Spring Data for Cassandra v1.5.10.Release.

I cannot find any reference that shows how to retrieve max(col) from Cassandra table using CassandraOperations and QueryBuilder. I tried below but it returns -
 Undefined column name "max(id)"

```
public class CassandraTest{

  @Autowired
  private CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;

  public void execute() {
    Select sel = QueryBuilder.select("max(id)").from("table").;
    Integer maxId= cassandraTemplate.queryForObject(sel, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("maxid ===> " + maxId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through [reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#cassandra.modules), I found out another way of doing it -old fashioned way without using QueryBuilder.

```
    String selectQuery = "select max(id) as maxId from table";      
    Integer maxId= csOps.selectOne(selectQuery, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("maxid ===> " + maxId);
```

I still want to know if it is possible with QueryBuilder. Interestingly, [datastax driver Select api](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.SelectionOrAlias.html#max-java.lang.Object-) supports max function.

```
public Select.SelectionOrAlias max(Object column)
Description copied from class: Select.Selection
Creates a max(x) built-in function call.
Overrides:
max in class Select.Selection
Returns:
the function call.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (although not tested):

```
Select sel = QueryBuilder.select().max(column("id")).from("table").;
```